# Guess the number game

Tags: c++, c

Think of a number between 1 and 100 in your mind.
Then, your program should ask you minimal # of questions and determine your number based on your answers.
Program's question format will be Is it NN (<, =, >)? 
You can respond to that question in 3 ways: < indicates that your number is less than computer's guess, = means that program guessed your number right, and > means that your number is greater than computer's guess. 
Allow the user to play this game any number of times. When the user is ready to quit, output average # of guesses / game.

Use a separate function to play the game. Invoke that function from main() repeatedly as needed.

So the output should look like this:

Guess a number between 1 and 100 (both inclusive) and get ready to answer a few questions.

Is it 50 (<,=,>)? <

Is it 25 (<,=,>)? <

Is it 12 (<,=,>)? >

Is it 18 (<,=,>)? >

Is it 21 (<,=,>)? <

Is it 19 (<,=,>)? >

Your guess is 20

It was a good game! Do you want to play again (y/n) ? y

Guess a number between 1 and 100 (both inclusive) and get ready to answer a few questions.

Is it 50 (<,=,>)? >

Is it 75 (<,=,>)? <

Is it 62 (<,=,>)? >

Is it 68 (<,=,>)? >

Is it 71 (<,=,>)? =

It was a good game!

Do you want to play again (y/n) ? n

---

This is what I have so far. However, the function playGame() is not even executed. It gives me the value 50 without any calculation.

```
while ((round = 0)){
    printf("How about %d", guess);
    scanf("%c", &ans);

    if((ans = '<')){
        upper = guess;
        guess = (upper+lower)/2;
    }
    else if ((ans = '>')){
        lower = guess;
        guess = (upper+lower)/2;
    }
    else {
        round = 1;
        printf("Your number is %d", guess);
    }
}
return guess;
}
```

Comment: Please use `fgets` in conjunction with `strcmp` to handle user input: both `scanf("%c", ...)` and `scanf("%s", ...)` are wrong (for different reasons). Please also accept an answer, since your original problem is fixed (ask another question if you want more help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `==` to compare two things, not `=`, which assigns one to the other. You've made this mistake in three places, so even after you fix `round = 0`, it'll treat every answer as `<` until you fix the other two.

From the double-brackets around the `if` conditions where you've done this, I assume the compiler warned you that you'd got this wrong, and you added the extra brackets to disable the warning. Don't ignore compiler warnings if you don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

```
while ((round = 0)){  // This is an assignment. It evaluates to zero and the loop
                      // never executes
```

Try

```
while ((round == 0)){  // This is a comparison.
```

Comment: Thank you, fixed that. Also when I input the first sign it automatically gives me the answer without asking further questions.
Like this:
`How about 50? <

How about 25? Your number is 25 

Do you want to play again? y/n`

Comment: Same problem. `if((ans = '<')){` should be `if((ans == '<')){`, and so on. Check all your comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

> the function playGame() is not even executed

Sure it is. What's not executed is your loop inside it, because

```
while ((round = 0))
```

is an assignment, not comparison.